# How do I make a bootable harddisk on Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, 15.04, iso

Hey everyone I just moved away from Windows you can guess,

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on my HDD located `/dev/sda1` on. How do I make a Linux Mint Cinnamon x64 ISO bootable on my harddisk located on `/dev/sdb1`?

I can't use the tool called Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1, 2, 3, because this is made for Windows but I know this tool can do the job.
I don't know how to use Linux, so can you tell me step by step what/how to open and what/how to install.

I thank you with all respect and support.

Please only answer if you know how my older was moved away because someone  false answered.

Comment: i want to install linux mint from my secondarry hdd

Comment: UNetBootin might be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the ISO you want.
2. Put it in an easy to access directory.
3. Open Terminal and run:

   cd /path/to/iso/directory/
   sudo dd if=example.iso of=/dev/sdb
4. Reboot and choose to boot from /dev/sdb

I hope this helps, good luck!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved this:

First, I installed `unetbootin`.  Then, I opened it via terminal with `sudo`.  Then, I used the command `unetbootin installtype=HDD targetdrive=/dev/sdb1`.  Then, I selected the iso file and it worked.

I installed Linux Mint, but i went back to Ubuntu.  This time, though, I used my pendrive

Comment: rather than being rude in your post, actually posting what you did to fix it as an answer is a better thing to do.

Comment: "you all was wrong thanks for trying" is a rude way of saying that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "Startup Disk Creator" feature built into ubuntu to make a USB key that installs ubuntu. Either this or a livecd can be used to install mint. Just remember to update grub bootloader when you are done :)
[image: Startup Disk Creator]
[image: Create Disk]

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to boot from an iso file that exists on your /dev/sdb1 volume,

First make sure grub is installed

`sudo update-grub`

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Find uuid of `/dev/sdb1`

`sudo blkid | grep /dev/sdb1`

Take note of uuid and fs type.

Then open your grub.cfg file for editing

`sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Go to line where you start seeing your menuentries they will be in format

```
menuentry Ubuntu Linux 
{
    some commands    
}
```

DONT edit existing entries just add a new one before `END`

```
 menuentry "Linux Mint" {
    insmod xxxx
    set root='(hd1,msdos0)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root yyyy
    loopback loop /linuxmint-16-mate-dvd-64bit.iso
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    (loop)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/linuxmint-16-mate-dvd-64bit.iso noeject noprompt --
    initrd    (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

You will have to change `/linuxmint-16-mate-dvd-64bit.iso` with path to your iso file

Change `xxxx` to your fs type

Change `yyyy` to your uuid

Reboot

Choose Linux Mint entry in grub at startup

This will boot your computer from iso, you can install it or use it as live cd.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this whole process, so maybe I can shed some light on the situation:

1. Put in a USB drive and download either the universal boot loader or the YUMI multiboot loader from pendrivelinux.com.
2. The program now will tell you what to do: onto the drive, it will tell you to identify the USB drive, then simply identify the iso you want to boot from.
3. Either press F12 at the start up on your computer or go to "advanced options" from the grub (linux boot page), and tell it to boot from the USB storage device.

the rest is up to you! The other option is to burn the ISO onto a cd through one of the many image burner programs (imgburn, freeisoburner, ect.) and tell the computer to boot through the cd drive, but for me this created problems and  was not as smooth as the USB option.