# Bootable hard disk image locked my hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery

I recently followed this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/678104)
in an attempt to create a Windows bootable hard disk.

Without any warning or confirmation, the console command chose and locked up my middle/largest hard drive with 7 years' worth of work on it. It doesn't appear to have been wiped as it shows a full red bar/full hard drive and data recovery software is showing that there are indeed files on the drive, or so it would seem.

Is this drive toast and those 7 years of work lost? What happened with that command that randomly chose that drive and locked it up like this?

The drive also had two hard disk images partitioned through it for Win10 and Kubuntu 23.10. Those also appear to be showing if that's what the "Basic data partition" represents.

[image: harddisk-details]

Comment: A dd command totally overwrites the destination. It has a nickname Data Destroyer. And drives can change. My sdc flash drive becomes sda when I reboot. So before running any dd command you have to be sure of device destination. Also if using dd to write an ISO to a larger drive, it erases the beginning of the drive to the size of the ISO. Beginning of drive is where partition & file details are, so you lost all the data at beginning of first partition up to size of ISO. Windows is also not configured for dd copy, so not the way to make a Windows installer.

Comment: I guess the major problem was i never knew Linux plays musical chairs with your disk drives even if you never accessed them. The bottom drive in my boot order in bios was given the label sdB and still it was never accessed by me once while working in my Kubuntu install. I'm still researching ways to recover the files, r-linux has seemingly found tons and tons of files but the drive remains locked to the size of the 3.6gb windows image; r-linux says it can recover lots of the files but i'm having trouble finding testimonials and examples of people doing it successfully in that program.

Comment: What format is drive or multiple partitions? Use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Often testdisk finds files by full file name, but if you have to resort to photorec then you only find files by extension. Sorting thru those to name them can take a long time. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk Do you have a backup of partition structure /partition table? If you find files best to immediately copy to another drive. Some have found files, but later lost everything.